# Environment variable ignored in Visual Studio Express 2012 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, environment-variables

I'm trying to open a solution in Visual Studio Express 2012 (which I think corresponds to Visual C++ 11, correct?).  In a project in the solution there are some lines like this:

```
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project=".\$(ProjectName)_vc110.props" />
    <Import Project="$(OTHER_LIB_ROOT)\path\to\myprops.props" />
    <Import Project="$(OTHER_LIB_ROOT)\path\to\myother.props" />
    <Import Project="$(OTHER_LIB_ROOT)\path\to\some.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

Where $(OTHER_LIB_ROOT) is a reference to an environment variable that points to a third-party software install on my local machine.

When I try to load up the solution, it cannot load the project, saying that it cant find "C:\path\to\myprops.props".  That to me says that it's replacing the variable with the empty string.  I know the variable exists, as I can start a command prompt and type "echo %OTHER_LIB_ROOT%" and it shows me the correct path.

I have tried restarting VS and even rebooting the machine, but it still doesn't work.  Is there something else I need to do to get it to pick up the correct value for the environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out there was a file that I hadn't looked in before, called ProjectName.props.  it contained the following stanza:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <OTHER_LIB_ROOT>../../../../..</OTHER_LIB_ROOT>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

That relative path was obsolete (I had cribbed the project out of one of the vendor's samples), and lead to a path that does not exist.  So I guess when VS tried to calculate the relative path it got "".

Once I changed the relative path to a valid absolute path, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. make a backup of the project.
   to solve this problem close the solution and create new one, then add new project property sheet and open up property manager and crete new property sheet.
   open this new property sheet and go to **common properties > user macros > add new macro**

type into name field OTHER_LIB_ROOT and 
type into value field "the path to the missing properties" EXCLUDE \path\to\myprops.props.

now save all and close solution.
open back the solution that has the problem and add this property sheet you just created to the project(not sure if you can add it to the unloaded projects, if so do it), if there is no project loaded create a new one.

save all and reload the solution.
I think this will work only if you have the misssing propertes in correct paths.

if that doesn't work then replace $(OTHER_LIB_ROOT) from your post with real path.

```
<Import Project="ADD REAL PATH HERE\path\to\myprops.props" />
```

or simply remove the lines from the project when you open it with text editor.